# RecyclerView OnClick Event Does Not Work

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I got some trouble while setting an onclicklistener to my recyclerview. I saw that similar question has been asked, I tryed all the ways I can find but I got no result. Here is how I implement it:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<Question> values;
private Context context;

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnClickListener{

    public TextView txtHeader;
    public View layout;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        layout = v;
        txtHeader = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.header);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d("Tag:", "Here");
        int position = getLayoutPosition();
        String question = values.get(position).getQuestion();
        String choiceA = values.get(position).getChoiceA();
        String choiceB = values.get(position).getChoiceB();
        String choiceC = values.get(position).getChoiceC();
        Integer questionID = values.get(position).getQuestionID();

        Intent intent = new Intent(context,SingleQuestionActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("question", question);
        intent.putExtra("choiceA", choiceA);
        intent.putExtra("choiceB", choiceB);
        intent.putExtra("choiceC", choiceC);
        intent.putExtra("questionID", questionID);

        QuestionActivity questionActivity =
                (QuestionActivity) context;

        questionActivity.goToSingleQuestionScreen(intent);
    }
}
...
```

As you can see I put an Log.d to see if it comes to onClick method it did not. And I set this adapter in my QuestionActivity class like below:

```
public class QuestionActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

...
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_question);
    initializeComponents();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    QuestionRepository questionRepository =
            QuestionRepository.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    questions = questionRepository
            .getCategorizedQuestions(intent.getIntExtra("category", 1));

    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(questions, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
...
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where have you set the clickListener?

Comment: @SubrataM. Yes I forgot to set it, thanks a lot!

Comment: you implement `OnClickListener` but whitch view have to handle this click event ? If it whole list item setOnClickListener for root view of ViewHolder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        layout = v;
        txtHeader = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.header);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily and cleanly done using Butterknife.

Add to your gradle file dependencies and sync project.

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

Now it is easier to set listeners and bind views. You could do the following:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.header) 
    TextView header;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

    @OnClick
    void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d("pos", getAdapterPosition());
        Intent intent ...
        ...
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

By using `@BindView` annotation you don't have to call `findViewById()`every time - Butterknife does that for you. Also you don't have to implement listeners - just add `@OnClick` annotation.

Also there is no need to get QuestionActivity and call its method from adapter (which I assume is starting another activity). Context can be obtained from `view.getContext()` as every view holds a reference to context and then you can call e.g. `startActivity(intent)`

For further reading I recommend

https://medium.com/@pranaypatel/butterknife-a-viewbinding-library-for-android-beginner-guide-fd92caf8e505

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidButterknife/article.html